# slicing with iloc and negative integer in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have been following this Python linear regression tutorial: https://medium.com/@contactsunny/linear-regression-in-python-using-scikit-learn-f0f7b125a204

Using the following dataset: 
https://github.com/contactsunny/data-science-examples/blob/master/salaryData.csv

My problem is with the following piece of code:

```
x = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
```

What does the negation(-1) do here? Why do I get an error If I use the following as an alternate:

```
x = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values
```

Comment: The -1 means position.  In the case of dataset.iloc[:, :-1] means get all columns except the last column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means, get all columns except the last column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(5,5)), index=[*'abcde'], columns=[*'ABCDE'])

df.iloc[:,:-1]
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D
a  79  23   9  89
b  67  60  32  82
c  66  18  41  67
d  90  51  63  29
e  34  65  82  82
```

This statement gets all rows and slices the columns to filter out the last.
And, there is no error by your second statement it is good statement.

```
df.iloc[:, 0]
```

Output:

```
a    79
b    67
c    66
d    90
e    34
Name: A, dtype: int3
```

Get all rows of the first column (position 0).